# Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a finite group, show $\{gh^{-1}:h\in G\} = G$ holds for any $g\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question is,

> Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a finite group, show $\{gh^{-1}:h\in G\} = G$ holds for any $g\in G$.

Anyone can help give some idea? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Show that the maps $m_g \colon G \to G$, $h \mapsto gh$ and $i \colon G \to G$, $h \mapsto h^{-1}$ are bijective by giving an inverse for each function. The restriction of $G$ being finite in unnecessary.

Comment: What are you stuck on, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: This seems like one of those "if you understand what it is asking it is trivial" problems.  It's saying for any element of G, then by multiplying g abut all inverses you get all elements of G.  As all elements have distinct inverses this just means  multiplying g by all element you get all elements of G.  As g*x = h, have a unique solution, this is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f \in G$  Then $f = ef = gg^{-1}f = g(g^{-1}f)$.  And note $(g^{-1}f)(f^{-1}g) = e$ so $(g^{-1}f) = (f^{-1}g)^{-1}$.

So $g(f^{-1}g)^{-1} = f$ so $f \in \{gh^{-1}| h \in G\}$ so $G \subseteq \{gh^{-1}| h \in G\}$

And, obviously, if $gh^{-1} \in \{gh^{-1}| h \in G\}$ then $gh^{-1} \in G$ so $\{gh^{-1}| h \in G\} \subseteq G$.

So $G = \{gh^{-1}| h \in G\}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=\{g_{1},...,g_{n}\}$. Fix $g_{1}=g$. We have $\{gh^{-1}:h\in G\}=\{gg_{1},gg_{2},...,gg_{n}\}$. If $gg_{i}=gg_{j}$ then $g^{-1}(gg_{i})=g^{-1}gg_{j}$, i.e., $g_{i}=g_{j}$; hence $i=j$. Then $|\{gg_{1},...,gg_{n}\}|=n=|G|$. Therefore $G=\{gg_{1},...,gg_{n}\}$.